# Subscript placement after \def containing superscript

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

If I do

```
\def\foo{V'}
$\foo_{i+1}$
```

the subscript gets wrongly placed, as if there were invisible parentheses around V'. I want the output to be the same as V'_{i+1}. How to get it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, according to a comment the OP left under David's answer, the problem was not caused by the code that was posted but by an invisible character. As such, this posting is not likely to be of much interest to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are expanded before the subscript is positioned, so it has no effect on the placement, See how the first two settings are identical.

[image]

```
\def\foo{V'}
$\foo_{i+1}$

$V'_{i+1}$

${V'}_{i+1}$

\bye
```

Comment: I figured it out... There was an undisplaying character in my code. DOH! (Probably alt+space on Linux...)